# Swift Compiler optimization for consecutive loop functions

Tags: ios, swift, macos, llvm

Does the LLVM compiler do any optimizations for consecutive Swift loop functions?

e.g:

```
var things: [String] = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
var changedThings = things.map({$0.characters}).map({$0.count})
```

versus:

```
var things: [String] = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
var changedThings = things.map({$0.characters.count})
```

In playgrounds it appears to run the expected 6 and 3 times respectively, but I'm unsure how reliable playgrounds behavior is compared to a full iOS or OSX app.

The reason being is there are many cases such as dealing with optionals where it's a lot cleaner to do something like:

`collection.flatMap($0.optional).map(otherThing.init)`

As compared to writing the whole thing in the flatMap function like:

`collection.flatMap { return $0.optional != nil ? otherThing(name: $0.optional!) : nil }`

There are of course a lot of options on how to include/reference a function to make that specific line cleaner, but I'm curious either way.